# Count the server calls from my application

Tags: java, cmis

I am working on a desktop application that connects to a repository and perform CRUD operations using CMIS API. CMIS API uses http communication internally. How can I know, the number of server calls performed by the desktop application.

Comment: could try logging using log4j or similar and then process the post log, or create a JmxBean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using OpenCMIS, set the log level of `org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.http.DefaultHttpInvoker` to debug. It logs every URL that is called by the client.